# How to get a description for each pin, in Google Maps for the iPhone

Tags: iphone, annotations, mkmapview

I have a problem with `MKPointAnnotation`. I want to create my iPhone application like this:

1. Show a pin in Google Maps
2. Show a description on each pin, pulling that description from a `NSMutableArray`.

So, My question is, how do I show a description on each pin?

This is my code:

```
 NSMutableArray *points = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
 for(int i=0; i < [dataTable count]; i++) {
   MKPointAnnotation *point =[[MKPointAnnotation alloc] init];
   CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate;
   coordinate.latitude = [[[dataTable objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"latitude"] floatValue];
   coordinate.longitude = [[[dataTable objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"longitude"] floatValue];
   [point setCoordinate:coordinate];
   [point setTitle:[[dataTable objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"name"]]; //-- name of pin
   [points addObject:point];
 }
 [map addAnnotations:points];
```

Answer (score 0):

I would adopt the MKAnnotation protocol in my own class and simply override the

```
 - (NSString) title
```

and implement

```
 - (CLLocationCoordinate2D) coordinate {
    CLLocationCoordinate2D theCoordinate;
    theCoordinate.latitude = self.latitude;
    theCoordinate.longitude = self.longitude;
    return theCoordinate; 
 }
```

My class would also have an initialiser that takes all the data it needs (from the array you mentioned)

```
- (id) initWithTitle:(NSString *)title_ andLatitude:(CLLocationDegrees)latitude_ andLongitude:(CLLocationDegrees)longitude_;
```

When iterating I would create my own objects and then add them to the collection of annotations.

Cheers...